# Mute sound after a certain time for Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, mute

Is there a way I can automatically disable sound on my PC after a certain time?

**Scenario:** I go to sleep. Someone calls me on Skype or my Gmail Notifier plus application makes an alarm notification for new email.

**Intended use-case:** PC is still running as I forgot to put it into sleep mode Since it is now after 11:00 PM, any sounds are muted.

Comment: You can use an auto-shutdown command to kill the PC after some time or *at* a certain time, I guess you want to keep it running?

Answer (score 6):

As explained in answers to a related question [[1](https://superuser.com/a/338005/208443)] , [[2](https://superuser.com/a/338072/208443)], you can use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), a small utility that does all kinds of stuff, including volume control, along with the Windows Task Scheduler.

Use `nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1` to mute the system volume, and use `nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 0` if you want to schedule a job that unmutes it again in the morning.

Microsoft provides step by step [documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) for using the task scheduler, but the basic process is simple:

1. Open Task Scheduler
2. Start the "Create New Task" wizard
3. Follow the wizard prompts to schedule your job.

Comment: @rath Thanks.  I wasn't sure what the proper way to reference the other question was, or if just leaving the duplicate comment was obvious enough.