# Is it possible to mute Windows after both a period of inactivity and a certain time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, mute

I've seen [Mute sound after a certain time for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/686216/mute-sound-after-a-certain-time-for-windows) and the related questions, but they don't quite hit on this. I don't want to just mute after a period of time - I've found that the quiet hours (the closest thing windows has) doesn't work well. For example, some days I'm at my computer past the quiet time, so then I have to unmute and I forget to mute when I walk away.

Is it possible to mute Windows after, say, 5 minutes of inactivity but *only* after a certain time? And auto unmute after a certain time?

Comment: I have modified the title and the question asked as your question if it remained the same will/would be closed because you are seeking for software recommendation. If my edit does not reflect what you asked properly, feel free to revert back to previous version of the question

Comment: This could likely be configured via a script set in Task Scheduler, but as to what scripting language to use and what commands, I haven't a clue; however, the task could be configured to run every x minutes checking for inactivity and if the parameter is met, mute via Powershell

Comment: The PowerShell commands I have seen to control Windows Audio are possible, but are a bit complicated. It is a solution that doesn't use third party tools though, and something can be said for that. I saw a Windows support forum link this PS script, but it is quite old, and may need adjustment for updated windows versions: http://asaconsultant.blogspot.com/2014/05/toying-with-audio-in-powershell.html

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks, the edit makes sense, I just wasn't sure if asking for a piece of software would be easier than trying to figure out a way to make windows do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with those solutions you already linked, but with a little more configuration in the task scheduler. It isn't a perfect solution, but you might not get a perfect solution without writing your own script. If you wanted to try that, you might have luck with VBscript or AutoHotKey.

With NirCmd application, this seems like the right utility to do the system mute, without needing to learn anything else.

The solution below will allow you to keep working on the PC, without it being muted, beyond your preconfigured start time. Once the computer goes idle, it will mute. Then you just need one more task to unmute in the morning.

For example, you want the computer to mute after 5 minutes of inactivity, but only between the hours of 8 PM and 7 AM.

When you setup your Mute task in Task Scheduler:

Triggers Tab:

- Begin task: On a Schedule
- Setting: Daily
- Start: Today at 8 PM
- Recur: 1 day
- Repeat task: 5 minutes
- For duration of: 11 hours (you can type anything into these fields)
- Stop all running tasks at end of repetition duration: Checked

Conditions Tab:

- Start the task only if computer is idle for: 5 minutes
- Wait for idle: Do not wait
- Stop if the computer ceases idle: Checked
- Restart if the idle state resumes: Checked

If you start working on your PC at anytime between 8 PM and 7 AM, and unmute it, once you go idle again, it will automatically mute after 5 minutes.

Then you just need a task at 7 AM that says to unmute the PC. This task doesn't need any special configuration except for the start trigger.

This is untested, so I might test this on my own, and if I see any issues or anything else to add, I'll come back and update this answer. I think this should work as described though.

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty good, I'll set it up and give it a try.